# What type of columns would be created executing this code?

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datacolumn, datacolumncollection

I have created a function that reads a Tab Delimited text file and create a data table as per it's header arrangement.

below is my code:

```
Private Function MakeDataTable(ByRef XSplitLine) As DataTable
    Dim AMZTable As New DataTable
    Dim i = 0
    For Each item In XSplitLine
        AMZTable.Columns.Add(XSplitLine(i).ToString)
        i += 1
    Next

    Return AMZTable
End Function
```

`XSplitLine` is an array that holds header Name(First Line in that text file) from a text file. As you can see I have not mentioned any data types while creating columns but still it executes without any error.

My question is what type of Value can be stored in these columns as I haven't mentioned it in the code?

Comment: You should use [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) so that Visual Studio can point out some problems in the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The datatype of the columns will be of type `String`.

As can be seen in https://referencesource.microsoft.com, the used overload of [`DataColumnCollection.Add`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataColumnCollection.cs,218) calls the constructor of [`DataColumn`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataColumn.cs,106) which accepts a string as argument.
This in turn calls the [constructor which accepts four arguments](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataColumn.cs,136) and sets the second argument (datatype) to `typeof(string)`.